# WHERE condition in SQL query from Excel sheet

Tags: c#, sql, excel

How can I use the `WHERE` condition in a SQL query when selecting from an Excel sheet?

This is my code

```
string chitty = "MTP/HG2";

DataTable dtdate = con.select("Select min(FirstInstDate) as FirstInstDate from [Sheet3$] where SeriesNo = "+chitty+" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DataTable dtdate = con.select("Select min(FirstInstDate) as FirstInstDate from [Sheet3$] where SeriesNo = '"+chitty+"'");
```